# Should DarkSky time machine (historical) data show PrecipAccumulation when precipType is "rain"

Tags: api, weather-api, darksky

At least for Daily?

https://api.darksky.net/forecast/[key]/42.3601,-71.0589,1554264000?exclude=minutely

(Date is `2019-04-03T04:00:00Z` and location is New York New York.

Daily shows:

```
 "daily": {
        "data": [
            {
                "apparentTemperatureHigh": 64.73,
                "apparentTemperatureHighTime": 1554325200,
                "apparentTemperatureLow": 36.19,
                "apparentTemperatureLowTime": 1554375600,
                "apparentTemperatureMax": 64.73,
                "apparentTemperatureMaxTime": 1554325200,
                "apparentTemperatureMin": 32.46,
                "apparentTemperatureMinTime": 1554289200,
                "cloudCover": 0.59,
                "dewPoint": 31.22,
                "humidity": 0.59,
                "icon": "rain",
                "moonPhase": 0.94,
                "ozone": 401.33,
                "precipIntensity": 0.0111,
                "precipIntensityMax": 0.0546,
                "precipIntensityMaxTime": 1554282000,
                "precipProbability": 1,
                "precipType": "rain",
                "pressure": 1013.35,
                "summary": "Rain in the morning.",
                "sunriseTime": 1554287063,
                "sunsetTime": 1554333169,
                "temperatureHigh": 64.73,
                "temperatureHighTime": 1554325200,
                "temperatureLow": 40.55,
                "temperatureLowTime": 1554375600,
                "temperatureMax": 64.73,
                "temperatureMaxTime": 1554325200,
                "temperatureMin": 38.61,
                "temperatureMinTime": 1554289200,
                "time": 1554264000,
                "uvIndex": 4,
                "uvIndexTime": 1554310800,
                "visibility": 8.45,
                "windBearing": 318,
                "windGust": 24.91,
                "windGustTime": 1554343200,
                "windSpeed": 6.28
            }
        ]
```

I see the manual says (https://darksky.net/dev/docs#time-machine-request):

> precipAccumulation optional, only on hourly and daily The amount of
>   snowfall accumulation expected to occur, in inches. (If no snowfall is
>   expected, this property will not be defined.)

And if it is snow-only then what represents the amount of rain that has fallen?

Answer (score 3):

I received a response from the Dark Sky team.

> Thank you for taking the time to write in. If you're looking for the
>   amount of rain that has fallen for a full day you can calculate it by
>   using the precipitation intensity either by the hour (sum up all
>   hours' precipitation intensity for the day) or by the day (multiply
>   the daily precipitation intensity by 24 for the hours). This is
>   something we're planning on providing in the new version of the API
>   but can easily be calculated by the end user as described.

That does make sense though I said I found it confusing to have a field that isn't being used (but the doco says it is (for snow fall)).

All good!